# tinymce IE11 (loosing focus - insertContent())

Tags: tinymce, internet-explorer-11

please have a look:

```
var mceBookmark;

function TbInsert(txt) {
  ed = tinymce.activeEditor;
  ed.selection.moveToBookmark(mceBookmark);
  ed.insertContent(txt);
  window.setTimeout(function() {$("#ed").tinymce().focus(); },200)
}
$('#myButton').on('mousedown', function() {mceBookmark = ed.selection.getBookmark(); });
```

Using tinymce 4.9.x but it's an old story: this code works fine except on IE(11).

$('#myButton') is a Button outside tinymce. By clicking it, IE looses focus and bookmark-position. insertContent() will allways push 'txt' on top of content.

I've also checked this to store bookmark-position:

```
setup: function (ed) {  
            ed.on('blur', function(e) {
                //mceBookmark = ed.selection.getBookmark();
           });
```

but this will force IE11 to crash.

What is the best practice to store and restore tinymce-bookmarks and how can i force incertContet() to push 'txt' at bookmark-position?

tnx!

Comment: Did IE gave any error before getting crashed? I check the documentation for 'selection.getBookmark();' which looks correct in above code. I hope you are not making test with any old document mode like IE 10 or IE 9 from IE 11 application. Because tinymce does not support older versions of IE. You can try to make a test with any other machine to check whether this is machine specific issue or it can be produce with any IE 11 app. If it can produce with any IE 11 than it is possible that there is some compatibility issue.